# perl6 what is the best way to enter multiple multi-line here-docs from $*IN

Tags: raku, getc

I need to enter multiple HERE-DOCs. My codes have 2 while loops. The inner loop is used to get the multi-line here-doc. But after I enter Control-D to complete one here-doc, then the inner while loop does not run again and the outer loop runs infinitely. What is the best way to fix it?

```
while True {
    my $y = ""; 
    my $x = 32;
    while $x=$*IN.getc { 
        $y = $y ~ $x; 
    }
    say "==========";
    say "[$y]"; sleep 2;
}
```

Why would $x continue to be EOF even after I reset $x to 32? Why would EOF be stuck in $*IN ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press Ctrl+D, the terminal closes the stdin stream on its end, and then when Perl 6 tries to continue to read from it, it always gets EOF.

In your program, this causes the inner `while` loop to end. You then set `$x` to `32` again, but at the next start of the inner `while` loop, the `$x = $*IN.getc` immediately sets it to `Nil` again, because the stream is still closed.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. I solved the problem by avoiding Ctrl-D all together. Thanks again smls !!